# Como eu verifico se uma senha está correta em um projeto de Caixa Eletrônico?

Tags: c#, lógica

Eu tenho um trabalho da faculdade no qual preciso criar uma espécie de caixa eletrônico em C#, em que tenho que criar duas textbox na qual eu tenho que inserir uma senha de quatro dígitos no primeiro, e aperacer a mesma senha mascarada no segundo.

A senha deve ser digitada em quatro buttons diferentes com três dígitos em cada. A parte do design tá de boa pra mim, minha dificuldade está na codificação.

Eu tenho que inserir a senha pelos botões, para aparecer na primeira textbox (visível), na segunda (mascarada). Caso a senha esteja correta deve aparecer a mensagem "`Senha OK`" e encerrar a aplicação.

Tentativas erradas só podem ocorrer duas vezes, se ocorrer a terceira deve aparecer a mensagem "`Cartão bloqueado`" e encerrar a aplicação.

[image: **inserir a descrição da imagem aqui**]

Comment: Qual código a senhorita tentou até o momento?:

Comment: Bom a unica coisa q fiz ate agora foi definir o tamanho da senha na primeira textbox defini o tamanho 4 (pois a senha deve ser de 4 digitos) e defini * na maskedTextBox.

Comment: Depende de onde está o usuário e a senha, mas provavelmente você precisa só comparar se a senha e o usuário batem com os valores que você tem armazenados. Para a faculdade, é possível que o professor aceite usuário e senhas no próprio código.

Comment: O valor dos botões vão ser fixos ou variáveis?

Comment: Eu gostaria que alguém me desse um help no código do array. E me desse um norte de como faço para que a inserida pelos botões apareçam    tanto na textbox qto na maskedbox. Essa form não tem um usuário definido, seria como se o usuário tivesse inserido o cartão e tivesse que digitar a senha.

Comment: Os valores dos botoes são fixos

Comment: Bom.. a senha deve ser digitado pelos 4 botoes. Digamos que a senha seja 5930, então devo apertar o primeiro botão da direita, o segundo da esquerda, o dadireita de cima e depois o da esquerda de baixo... Essa senha deve aparacer na textbox em ****, porém meu professor quer que a senha digitada apareça na textbox de modo visível tb... A única coisa que sei é são 4 ifs primeiro para ver se a sequencia dos botoes batem, e que depois tem outros ifs para verficar se as sequencias dos numeros de dentro dos botões batem com a senha.

Comment: Tb não sei exatamente que comando que uso para encerrar a aplicação, o que deverá ocorrer tanto colocando a senha correta, qto passando o numero maximo de tentativas erradas.

Comment: @AnaPaulaVieira você poderia mostrar onde é o ponto especifico que você esta tendo dificuldade? Me parece que falta base para você, mas, se você dividir esses problema em varias partes especificas talvez de para soluciona-lo.

Comment: Poste seu código também, assim fica melhor para a comunidade entender.

Comment: o seu textbox que ira receber a senha do usuario e mostrar a mesma  dever ser a normal  porem  a que ira receber a senha do mesmo  mascarada dever ser a do tipo senha que ao digitar o mesmo ja apareça mascarado.. ai  basta vc "setar" o botão para ambos os text box    segue um exemplo  .. esse codigo e em java  não sei como ficaria em c# ..  button.setText("localdesejado1");  e button.setText("localdesejado2"); nesse caso ele mostraria em ambos os textbox porem no texbox padrao  iria aparecer a senha ja no outro  por ser do tipo "senha"  iria aparecer mascarado .. espero que tenha ajudado.